# Cryptic clue: She loses...[8]

Tags: cryptic-clues

Cryptic type clue

> She loses me measuring acid of insect, which is a large animal? [8]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not fully worked out but I guess the answer is

> ELEPHANT

Partial explanation:

> 'measuring acid of insect' gives pH + ant, so presumably "She loses me" indicates ELE somehow. I'd expect this would be something like a female name with ME (or I or TOM) removed but I'm not seeing anything...

Comment: Probably ME+(First 3 letters of the answer) is a female name in the part of the world where the OP is at?

Comment: Hmmmm think of a synonym for `me`  - you are nearly nearly there...

Comment: Ok bigger hint for final bit .... Imagine she is french

Comment: Hmmm. Do you ask us to remove I from _elle_ to get  ELE? I hope not, because the capital I isn't an L. (And foreign words should be indicated, for example "In France, she ...")

Comment: I'm guessing it's simply rot13(Ryvr - v = Ryr).

Comment: @Statman: But that's the French equivalent of rot13(Ryvnf, fb cebonoyl abg "fur".)

Comment: oh dear I am breaking all the rules -- so capital I looks like the what needs to be removed from Elle.... maybe I should just give up on the cryptic clues so I isn't an L, but it does look like the lower case one that needs to be removed... and by the time you know what you are looking for if the rest of the clues fit together............... OK alternatively you can get the required 3 letters from a female name which includes i as the 3rd letter of four with the other 3 in the same order.